# How do I flexbox using html css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My friend told me about able to flexbox in HTML to make things nice. I wonder how do I make things "flexbox" I don't understand?

i try

```
<flexbox> my text </flexbox>
```

but nothing work

Comment: get started [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and if you have some issues, post on SO

Comment: Flexbox is a Browser Module, a capability, and you can use it via css properties, more info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: There is no `<flexbox>` HTML tag; it is configured with CSS. To start, set an element's CSS `display` attribute like `display: flex`. CSS Tricks has a great [flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to get you started.

Comment: It's best to use stack overflow for issues that you're having, not an overall tutorial. The link provided by @NidhinJoseph is great and should get you started. When you have a bit more code, update your answer & we will help you debug any issues you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex is specified in the CSS, no JS needed

First create your element in the HTML and give it a class

```
<div class="my__flexbox">This will be a flexbox</div>
```

Then using CSS you would reference your class and add a `display: flex` rule.

```
.my__flexbox {
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a container such as *div* in html and assign it a class.
HTML would look like this:

```
<div classname="flexbox-container">
</div>
```

and the CSS goes like this:

```
.flexbox-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column; //Default direction is row. Everything inside this 
                        container would be in a single row.
}
```

To learn more about flexbox, you can visit: https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/css-flexbox